# How do get my submit button to generate the message based on my switch statements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
function displayMessage() {
    var message;
    var firstName= alert(
    switch(firstName) {
    case "Cherry":
        message="Thank You Cherry!! Your order should arrive 20 days from 
        February 4, 2017";
        break;
    case "Micheal":
        message = "Thank You Micheal!! Your order will be coming in two weeks";
        break;
    case "Sandra":
        message = "Thank You Sandra!! You've got a big order so it will take a month.";
        break;
    case "Cookie": 
        message= "Thank You Cookie!! Your order is coming tomorrow. So be at home between 1-2pm." 
    
    }
    document.getElementById("generate").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Cookie Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="First_Design.css">
    <script src="cookieform.js"></script>
    <script src="DisplayNames.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cookie Order Form</h1>
    <p>This form is a cookie order form for customers that purchased cookies from Daron's Cookies Company and the following below must be filled out in order for each customer to receive a final message that tells them when their order will be ready.</p>


    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">



    <!--The customer will be sent to the HTML page named "submit.html" after they
  click the "Submit this Form" button. The code below does this. -->
    <div>
        <form id="cookie_form" action="#">

            <fieldset class="field_set_1">
                <!-- Below sets the title of the form-->
            
                <legend>Customer Order Form Information:</legend>


                <!-- Creates the first left label to specify what should be placed in the text box
                to the right of the label. The rest below does the same.-->

                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
                <span id="firstname_error">*</span><br>

                <label for="orderNumber">Order Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
                <span id="orderNumber_error">*</span><br>

                <label for="date_of_order">Date of Order:</label>
                <input type="text" id="date_of_order" name="date_of_order">
                <span id="date_of_order_error">*</span><br>

                <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
                <span id="email_address_error">*</span><br>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
           <input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this form" 
            onclick="displayMessage()">
            <p id="generate"></p>
            </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">


</body>



</html>
```

How do I get my submit button in HTML to generate the different messages based on my displayMessage() function of switch statements in Javascript? I am asking this because I thought about extracting first names of users on one page and using them on the final page in order to display a message towards each user, but I see that hasn't worked out for me yet. So now I think I am going to use switch statements based on the user's firstname input value. How can I do that? I am only concerned with getting the correct message based on their firstname of when they entered it on the html form and clicked submit. Here is my html form and Javascript.

Comment: If your plan is to submit content to a server, then you should get this data back from the server and then display it on the last page. When you submit a form (from my understanding you will load completely new html page) then you will loose all client-side data from first html page including javascript too. My suggestion to you is to use NodeJS for a backend because it's one of the easiest backend frameworks to begin with.

Comment: No, I want a popup window to display the message based on their first names. I shouldn't have do to ASP or any server-side programming to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayMessage()
    {
            var message;
            var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
            switch(firstName)
              {
                case "Cherry":
                    message="Thank You Cherry!! Your order should arrive 20 days from February 4, 2017";
                    break;
                case "Micheal":
                    message = "Thank You Micheal!! Your order will be coming in two weeks";
                    break;
                case "Sandra":
                    message = "Thank You Sandra!! You've got a big order so it will take a month.";
                    break;
                case "Cookie": 
                    message= "Thank You Cookie!! Your order is coming tomorrow. So be at home between 1-2pm." 

             }
          alert(message);
   }
```

If you want to do this you must **GET firstname from form to your function**.

```
var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
```

Takes the firstname from form and let your function to finish it's job.

Comment: Mark as answered, maybe it will be helpful to someone else ;)

Comment: – Vykintas I tested it but not happened on my html page

Answer (score 0):

```js
function displayMessage() {
    var message;
    var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    switch(firstName) {
    case "Cherry":
        message="Thank You Cherry!! Your order should arrive 20 days from February 4, 2017";
        break;
    case "Micheal":
        message = "Thank You Micheal!! Your order will be coming in two weeks";
        break;
    case "Sandra":
        message = "Thank You Sandra!! You've got a big order so it will take a month.";
        break;
    case "Cookie": 
        message= "Thank You Cookie!! Your order is coming tomorrow. So be at home between 1-2pm." 
    
    }
    alert(message);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Cookie Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="First_Design.css">
    <script src="cookieform.js"></script>
    <script src="DisplayNames.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cookie Order Form</h1>
    <p>This form is a cookie order form for customers that purchased cookies from Daron's Cookies Company and the following below must be filled out in order for each customer to receive a final message that tells them when their order will be ready.</p>


    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">



    <!--The customer will be sent to the HTML page named "submit.html" after they
  click the "Submit this Form" button. The code below does this. -->
    <div>
        <form id="cookie_form" action="#">

            <fieldset class="field_set_1">
                <!-- Below sets the title of the form-->
            
                <legend>Customer Order Form Information:</legend>


                <!-- Creates the first left label to specify what should be placed in the text box
                to the right of the label. The rest below does the same.-->

                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
                <span id="firstname_error">*</span><br>

                <label for="orderNumber">Order Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
                <span id="orderNumber_error">*</span><br>

                <label for="date_of_order">Date of Order:</label>
                <input type="text" id="date_of_order" name="date_of_order">
                <span id="date_of_order_error">*</span><br>

                <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
                <span id="email_address_error">*</span><br>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
           <input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this form" 
            onclick="displayMessage()">
            <p id="generate"></p>
            </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cookie Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="First_Design.css">
    <script src="cookieform.js"></script>
    <script src="DisplayNames.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cookie Order Form</h1>
    <p>This form is a cookie order form for customers that purchased cookies from Daron's Cookies Company and the following below must be filled out in order for each customer to receive a final message that tells them when their order will be ready.</p>
    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">
    <!--The customer will be sent to the HTML page named "submit.html" after they
  click the "Submit this Form" button. The code below does this. -->
    <div>
        <form id="cookie_form" action="#">
            <fieldset class="field_set_1">
                <!-- Below sets the title of the form-->
                <legend>Customer Order Form Information:</legend>
                <!-- Creates the first left label to specify what should be placed in the text box
                to the right of the label. The rest below does the same.-->
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
                <span id="firstname_error">*</span><br>
                <label for="orderNumber">Order Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
                <span id="orderNumber_error">*</span><br>
                <label for="date_of_order">Date of Order:</label>
                <input type="text" id="date_of_order" name="date_of_order">
                <span id="date_of_order_error">*</span><br>
                <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
                <span id="email_address_error">*</span><br>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
           <input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this form" 
            onclick="displayMessage()">
            <p id="generate"></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">
<script>
favorite
function displayMessage() {
    var message;
    var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    switch(firstName) {
    case "Cherry":
        message="Thank You Cherry!! Your order should arrive 20 days from February 4, 2017";
        break;
    case "Micheal":
        message = "Thank You Micheal!! Your order will be coming in two weeks";
        break;
    case "Sandra":
        message = "Thank You Sandra!! You've got a big order so it will take a month.";
        break;
    case "Cookie": 
        message= "Thank You Cookie!! Your order is coming tomorrow. So be at home between 1-2pm." 

    }
    alert(message);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vykintas  can't I use external js too?

Comment: You need external javascript?

Comment: For example I saved javascript code to file named "FNS.js" in the same directory as HTML file. Then in HTML file I REPLACED tag SCRIPT content to "<script src='FNC.js'></script>" and It works ;)

Comment: Don't forget to include script AFTER all html

Comment: I did external JS, and mines still doesn't work. Is it something wrong with my submit button?

Comment: If your submit button code is still '<input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this form" 
            onclick="displayMessage()">', than no

Comment: onclick="displayMessage()" - is a must for this button

Comment: Do you included script AFTER form?

Comment: Yeah I included it AFTER

Comment: If button have 'onclick="displayMessage()" ', than there is no need to change it

Comment: If script included after form and its path correct it should work

Comment: Check the script path

Comment: Then how it doesn't work for me but it works for you. I am so confused!

Comment: I think you make a mistake by including the script

Comment: Do you make online project?

Comment: In the external javascript or in the internal javascript

Comment: No just html pages

Answer (score 0):

HTML file content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cookie Order Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="First_Design.css">
    <script src="cookieform.js"></script>
    <script src="DisplayNames.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cookie Order Form</h1>
    <p>This form is a cookie order form for customers that purchased cookies from Daron's Cookies Company and the following below must be filled out in order for each customer to receive a final message that tells them when their order will be ready.</p>
    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">
    <!--The customer will be sent to the HTML page named "submit.html" after they
  click the "Submit this Form" button. The code below does this. -->
    <div>
        <form id="cookie_form" action="#">
            <fieldset class="field_set_1">
                <!-- Below sets the title of the form-->
                <legend>Customer Order Form Information:</legend>
                <!-- Creates the first left label to specify what should be placed in the text box
                to the right of the label. The rest below does the same.-->
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
                <span id="firstname_error">*</span><br>
                <label for="orderNumber">Order Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
                <span id="orderNumber_error">*</span><br>
                <label for="date_of_order">Date of Order:</label>
                <input type="text" id="date_of_order" name="date_of_order">
                <span id="date_of_order_error">*</span><br>
                <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
                <span id="email_address_error">*</span><br>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
           <input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this form" 
            onclick="displayMessage()">
            <p id="generate"></p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix">
    </div>
    <IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
    <IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">
<script src="FNC.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript file "FNC.js" content

```
function displayMessage() {
    var message;
    var firstName=document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    switch(firstName) {
    case "Cherry":
        message="Thank You Cherry!! Your order should arrive 20 days from February 4, 2017";
        break;
    case "Micheal":
        message = "Thank You Micheal!! Your order will be coming in two weeks";
        break;
    case "Sandra":
        message = "Thank You Sandra!! You've got a big order so it will take a month.";
        break;
    case "Cookie": 
        message= "Thank You Cookie!! Your order is coming tomorrow. So be at home between 1-2pm." 

    }
    alert(message);
}
```

Place both files in same directory